# redirect www.mydomain.com/page to subdir.mydomain.com?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have a number of clients in the field accessing a web service using a format like this: www.mydomain.com/page/

I would like to redirect that URL to subdomain.mydomain.com/, where www.mydomain.com is on one server and subdomain.mydomain.com is on another server. Both servers have comfortable and functional homes in the DNS zone records.

I have some knowledge of Apache Redirect, but I cannot get this one quite right. Suggestions and links to articles are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you You need to see Apache Mod_Rewrite

create .htaccess file on root of www.mydomain.com/

and place something like following in .htaccess, 
it is a permanent redirect (301)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Above rule should redirects

mydomain.com/page1.html

to

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/page1.html

Again Please See Apache Mod_Rewrite for details.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple text-book [mod_alias `Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you could use on any context (server config, virtual host, directory, `.htaccess`).

```
Redirect /page1/ http://subdomain1.example.com/
Redirect /page2/ http://subdomain2.example.com/
```

If you also need to redirect `/page1` without the `/` you can remove it, but remember that it'll also match anything else with the same beginning, e.g. `/page14`.